# Spring Boot custom paging parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am trying to override the default param name fo page size in Spring JPA to match that of the Kendo UI grid which needs to use

http://localhost:8080/retailers/all?page=1&pageSize=5

The JPA is producing

http://localhost:8080/retailers/all?page=1&size=5

I have tried adding

```
spring.data.rest.page-param-name=page
spring.data.rest.limitParamName=pageSize
```

to the application properties, but it doesn't seem to make any difference to the project.

My controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "retailers/all")
public ResponseEntity<Page<RetailerEntity>> retailers(Pageable pageable){
    Page<RetailerEntity> retailers = retailerService.getAllRetailers(pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(retailers, HttpStatus.OK);  
}
```

and the repository is using the out of the box implementation

```
public interface RetailerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<RetailerEntity, Integer> {

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you tell us which spring boot version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be related to the spring boot version. 
Changing application.properties works only for Spring Boot 1.2+.
If you are using 1.1 or earlier version, you have two options:

1) Create a `RepositoryRestConfigurer` bean using a custom implementation of `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Configuration
class CustomRestMvcConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {

    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setBasePath("/api");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

2) Create a component with a custom implementation of `RepositoryRestConfigurer`.

```
@Component
public class CustomizedRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.setBasePath("/api");
  }
}
```

These examples are for the `basePath` property, you can change all the others in the same way.
You can check for more details: [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri)

Comment: I am using parent starter 1.5.4.RELEASE, It still doesn't update the entries in the properties file.  I've been able to work around it by changing the client side parameters, but I thought this would be easier.